# Scrolling the following and followers list with selenium(Python)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver

Hey I am trying to make a simple Insta bot using selenium.I reached up to my following list by automating but now I don't know how I can scroll down the list of my following/followers. I want to grab the account from my following and followers list and compare it and make a list of the accounts who havenot followed me back.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from time import sleep
from secrets import password,username


class Instabot:
    def __init__(self,username,password):
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Users\\user\\PycharmProjects\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe")
    self.driver.get("https://www.instagram.com")

    sleep(5)

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[2]/div/label/input').send_keys(username) #searching the username box and giving it username

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[3]/div/label/input').send_keys(password)#searching the password box and giving it password

    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/main/article/div[2]/div[1]/div/form/div[4]/button').click() #clicking login button

    wait=WebDriverWait(self.driver,10)

    notNowButton = wait.until(
        lambda d: d.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]'))#it will click on first notnow button


    notNowButton.click()

    next_not_now=wait.until(lambda notnow:notnow.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="Not Now"]'))
    next_not_now.click() #it will click on second not now button

def get_unfollowers(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    clickprofile= wait.until(lambda a: a.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="react-root"]/section/nav/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[5]/a'))
    clickprofile.click()

    following_list = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href,'/following')]")))
    following_list.click()#IT clicks the following and gives window of following listy
    print("CLicked following list")
   


my_bot=Instabot(username,password)
my_bot.get_unfollowers()
```

I saw about execute_script() But I dont know what to put under those brackets.

Well I figure it out. This code works for me now!

```
fBody = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div[class='isgrP']")
    scrolling_times=(numoffollowers/4)
    scroll=0
    scroll_count = scrolling_times+5  #  You can use your own logic to scroll down till the bottom
    while scroll < scroll_count:
        self.driver.execute_script(
            'arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollTop + arguments[0].offsetHeight;',
            fBody)
        sleep(2)
        scroll += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like that :

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, Y)")
```

with Y : how much you want to scroll in pixel.

It's up to you to see how far down you have to go down.

Comment: I  got "selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Y is not defined" error what to define in Y and I mean what i should define in Y? I have to go till the last account so what can i do for it? I don't know logic for it!!

Comment: You need to put a number instead of Y. Like « window.scrollTo(0,10) »

Comment: It didnot work!!! Any other ideas for it? or is it impossible?